# How to calculate a matrix raised to any power but with pretending the sign of the numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Lets say the given matrix would be:

```
A = array([[ 5.,  6.,  4.,  1.],
           [-4., -1., -7., -4.],
           [ 2., -3.,  9.,  8.]])
```

and I want to raise the matrix `A` to the power `p = 1.05`.

For positive integers it is not a problem, but I want to raise the negative numbers too to the p power with pretending the negative sign  (otherwise the numbers will be `nan` in numpy).

Here is the example of `A_pow = A**p`:

```
A_pow = array([[  5.41899193,   6.56234129,   4.28709385,   1.        ],
               [         nan,          nan,          nan,          nan],
               [  2.07052985,          nan,  10.04510857,   8.87655578]])
```

My approach was something like this (for the matrix `B`):

```
B = A.copy()
B[B > 0.0] = B[B > 0.0]**p
B[B < 0.0] = -np.abs(B[B < 0.0])**p
```

Which gives me:

```
B = array([[  5.41899193,   6.56234129,   4.28709385,   1.        ],
           [ -4.28709385,  -1.        ,  -7.71530221,  -4.28709385],
           [  2.07052985,  -3.16940193,  10.04510857,   8.87655578]])
```

Is there any other or better way to approach the same goal?

Comment: Why do you think raising a negative number to a power results in NaN?

Comment: @ScottHunter Fractional powers aren't defined for negative numbers...?

Comment: If you have e.g. (-2)**2, this is 4. But (-2)**x where x can be any positive number is not defined, mathematically. (-2)**1.5 = (-2)**(3/2) = ((-2)**3)**(1/2) = (-8)**(1/2) = 8**(1/2)*i is a complex number.
Therefore in the numpy array this numbers are nan, because only real numbers are defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.abs`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.absolute.html#numpy.absolute) + [`np.sign`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) -

```
(np.abs(A) ** 1.05) * np.sign(A)

array([[  5.41899193,   6.56234129,   4.28709385,   1.        ],
       [ -4.28709385,  -1.        ,  -7.71530221,  -4.28709385],
       [  2.07052985,  -3.16940193,  10.04510857,   8.87655578]])
```

`np.sign` retrieves the sign of each element. Then, convert the array to its absolute with `np.abs`, find the power, and multiply by the sign mask.